# Interoperability with Java in Frege, especially in IO Monad

Tags: java, haskell, frege

I would like to translate this java code into Frege Haskell:

```
    PApplet pApplet = new PApplet();
    System.out.print(pApplet.toString());
    PApplet.runSketch(new String[]{"test"}, pApplet);
```

I did so far:

```
data PApplet = mutable native processing.core.PApplet
  where
    native new :: () -> IO PApplet
    native toString :: PApplet -> IO String

native runSketch processing.core.PApplet.runSketch
  :: ArrayOf RealWorld String -> PApplet -> IO ()

main _ = do p <- PApplet.new
            pStr <- p.toString
            putStrLn pStr
            args = JArray.fromList ["test"]
            runSketch args p
```

Part up to `main` compiles but then I get those errors:

```
E Process.fr:14: type error in expression fromList ("test":[])
    type is : STMutable t1 (JArray String)
    expected: ArrayOf RealWorld String
E Process.fr:15: type error in expression p
    type is : IO PApplet
    expected: PApplet
E Process.fr:12: type error in expression >>= p.toString (λpStr -> >> (putStrLn pStr) (runSketch (fromList ("test":[])) p))
    type is : IO ()
    expected: ()→t1
E Process.fr:11: type error in expression λp -> >>= p.toString (λpStr -> >> (putStrLn pStr) (runSketch (fromList ("test":[])) p))
    type is : IO ()
    expected: ()→t1
E Process.fr:11: type error in expression >>= new (λp -> >>= p.toString (λpStr -> >> (putStrLn pStr) (runSketch (fromList ("test":[])) p)))
    type is : ()→t1
    expected: IO ()
E Process.fr:11: type error in expression λ_ -> >>= new (λp -> >>= p.toString (λpStr -> >> (putStrLn pStr) (runSketch (fromList ("test":[])) p)))
    type is : ()→t1
    expected: IO ()
E Process.fr:12: can't find a type for  p.toString `toString`
    is neither an overloaded function nor a member of  IO PApplet
```

I'm trying hard to meet compiler criteria, but without success. After countless random combinations this snippet above seems the most reasonable to me. Do I need type hints in `do` block? I don't get why `p <- PApplet.new` evaluates into `IO PApplet`? and how to make `JArray.fromList` to return `ArrayOf RealWorld String` ? Frege is great but interoperability is quite daunting. Is it possible to have more examples focused on it on Frege github?

Comment: I'm not familiar with frege so I'm assuming it is sufficiently similair to Haskell. You declared `PApplet.new` to have type `() -> IO PApplet`, but you've used it without an argument: `p <- PApplet.new` should be `p <- PApplet.new ()` (and `pStr <- p.toString` should be `pStr <- p.toString p`). The line `p <- PApplet.new` is *not* a type error, however, because `(->) ()` is a monad! The compiler believes you are working in this monad, not IO. I think that the first error (regarding `fromList ("test":[])`) is unrelated, but the errors complaining about `()→t1` are due to this one omission.

Comment: Yes, calling `PApplet.new` without `()` is a cause of most compiler complains! Really silly am I.

Comment: Now the question is simply about how to get rid of `Process.fr:14: type error in expression fromList ("test":[])   type is : STMutable t1 (JArray String)   expected: ArrayOf RealWorld String`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have

```
ST s X
```

and you want

```
X
```

and you are in `IO`, which is nothing but `ST RealWorld`

So, the most natural solution would be to replce the `=` with `<-` in the line

```
args = JArray.fromList ["test"]
```

and you're set!

Granted, the whole story is a bit difficult because of the type aliases:

```
type ArrayOf a x = Mutable a (JArray x)
type STMutable s a = ST s (Mutable s a)
```

Had the de-aliaser choosen to translate

```
ST s (Mutable s (JArray String))
```

back to

```
ST s (ArrayOf s String)
```

you probably would have seen it.